# Display Div text on mouse hover using css

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am new to css and ui designing. 
Here's the case.
I have a div(divmain). Inside that divmain, I have an image and another div (sub_div). There are texts inside sub_div which I want to display on mouse hover, hidden otherwise using just css (no javascript/jquery).
Kindly suggest the approach I should follow.

Right now I am doing something like:

**Html:**

```
<div class="divmain">
<img src="" />
<div class="sub_div">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.divmain .sub_div {
    height: 70px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    margin-top: 35px;
    line-height: 70px;

}

.divmain:hover .sub_div {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What is it about your current method that isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Below Code should help you:

```css
.divmain{
width: 200px;
}

.sub_div{
display:none; /* This code hides the text initially */
/* Your sub_div styles can go here*/
 }

.divmain:hover .sub_div{
  display:block; /*Here we are making the .sub_div visible on hover*/
}
```

```html
<div class="divmain">
<img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/EC4hMSt.png" width="200px" height="auto" />
<div class="sub_div">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
<div class="divmain">
<img src="mrm.gif" alt="Smiley face" />
<div class="sub_div">Some Text</div>
</div>

.divmain .sub_div {
      display: none;
}

.divmain:hover .sub_div {
    display: block;
}
```

[Click to view CodePen](http://codepen.io/manaranjan/pen/yJKorO)